# QuickSight - count distinct of two columns

Tags: count, distinct, amazon-quicksight, distinct-values

I need help with figuring out how to perform count distinct over two columns in QuickSight - find the number of unique combinations of values from two columns. Example below would result in 4

| column1 | center |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 87 |
| apple | 87 |
| banana | 34 |
| blueberry | 45 |
| blueberry | 32 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it. You can simply put the `center` field in a field well and use the `Count distinct` aggregation as shown below

[image: Count distinct]

Alternatively, you can create a calculated field for this count with the following definition:

```
distinct_count({center})
```